# how to share API (api.yaml) in git?

Tags: java, spring, git, api, openapi

I've microservice architecture with openapi generated API (code first) in api.yml which is used by many microservices. In case of changes I need to go to a particular microservices git repo and copy `api.yml` from there, then paste to another microservice an generate feign client from it.

How can I share `api.yml` between microservices?

Comment: I think submodules with symlinks could help but not much. You have to run `git submodule update --remote` and then `git commit` in every repository anyway. You won't do this manually, you will write a script for that. In that case why not just write a script that copies the file to all repositories, add and commit?

Comment: An option is to publish the file to a (Maven) repository (e.g. as a library), and have your projects depend on that library, the downside of that is versioning or having to use version ranges.